# SSIS - Mapping one variable to another before linking it to the dataflow task

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using 3 variables in an ssis project to convert a datetime value to string. 
Variable 1 is a simple datetime
Variable 2 converts Variable1 into a string
Variable 3 is an SQL command that is used by a dataflow task (Access Mode : SQL Command From Variable.)

On every run, the Variable1 is updated. I need to link Variable 2 to the dataflow task. How can i link variable 2and variable 1? As  its not showing the updated values.

Answer (score 0):

You can give Variable2 an expression in which it converts the date in Var1 to string:

```
(DT_WSTR, 4)YEAR( @[User::Variable1])
+ RIGHT("00" + (DT_WSTR, 2)MONTH( @[User::Variable1]), 2)
+ RIGHT("00" + (DT_WSTR, 2)DAY( @[User::Variable1]), 2)
```

This outputs a date (ie today) as `20150803`. This should work dynamically; Var2 will at all times reflect the current value of Var1.